# Computer monitor dataset listing display size, resolution and weight

Tags: data-request

I'm looking for a data set listing computer models with at least the following information:

- display size (e.g., 24 inches)
- resolution (e.g.,1920x1080)
- weight

Answer (score -1):

you can search it on the website "https://www.kaggle.com/".

Comment: Hi Janadari, this is essentially a link only answer, which does not fit our required format. Can you please elaborate on this? And by elaborating, I mean pointing to real resources and not explaining how to search kaggle. Thank you.